# Тестирование входящих в Телеграмм бот сообщений

Tags: python, telegram-bot, юнит-тесты, pytest

Есть простой телеграмм бот, написанный на библиотеке python-telegram-bot, суть которого отвечать на простые сообщения формата **"Привет!"** - (ответ)добрый день!. **"Как дела?"** - (ответ)более менее. Вопрос, как мне в рамках какой-нибудь тестовой библиотеки отправить в бот текстовое сообщение "Привет!" и "Как дела?", что бы в дальнейшем сравнить полученные ответы с ожидаемыми (добрый день! и более менее). Пробовал отправлять сообщение через клиент АПИ, но в бот это сделать не удается, только обычным пользователям. Думал создать сообщения отдельным объектом и заменить прилетающий в **update** - **['message']** на свой самопальный, но реализация хромает, так как не до конца понимаю как это можно вделать

Comment: можно использовать библиотеку telethon, это юзер бот

Comment: Вообщм почитал доку по pyrogram и telethon. В обоих оказывается через клиент можно было отправлять сообщения боту, просто я этого не понял, спасибо за помощь"